# How to set up a custom template on Serilog ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, serilog

I'm learning how to send logs into ElasticSearch, and I'm using Serilog for this. I'm already able to send logs, but on Kibana my field appears with a exclamation, saying that that is no cached mapping for my field.

I searched about it, and I think that is something with the template. Is that right?

How to map fields in Serilog Elastic Search?

i'm sending logs this way:

`Log.Information("{Message} {System}", "Hello, I'm on Index", "Teste");`

Comment: I think you mean `mappings` not `template` if I understood you correctly. Also, you need JSON style documents to create `mappings`

Comment: @JBone I solved that exclamation, just needed to refresh item list on Kibana. But by default Serilog sends a lot of information, this is related to the template, right? How do I change that?

Answer (score 0):

First lets get some terms right.

Every index, e.g. `mylogs-2022-07-27`, has a **mapping**. A mapping describes what fields are in the index and what type they have (and more, but that's enough for now). Doc: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html

**Index templates** describe mappings to create for future indicies (and more...). Index templates have a field `index_patterns` which is used to determine for which indicies this template should be used. E.g. `mylogs-*`. So every index which name starts with mylogs- will have the mapping described in the index template. Doc: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-templates.html

Kibana uses `index patterns`. You can create it in Kibana under `Management > Index Patterns`. Strictly speaking, this has nothing to do with mappings or index templates. It is something specific to Kibana and tells it what fields are in the index and what types they have. Fields in an index pattern have some additional Kibana related information which the user can change, which is the reason (I guess) Kibana uses index patterns and not the mapping itself.

Now for your question... If you have a field in your mapping, but it is missing from the index pattern, you get the problem you faced of Kibana showing an exclamation mark. Solution is to refresh your index pattern under `Management > Index Patterns > mylogs-*`. You will find a button with an alt text similar to "Refresh field list".